# Arraylist.contains retorna siempre falso

Tags: java, clase

Estoy intentando programar una simple app que emula una lista de contactos en un celular.

Creo un contacto y lo guardo correctamente en el arrayList, sin embargo al invocar arraylist.contains y buscando por el nombre por el cual guardé el contacto, el método retorna siempre falso. Por qué?

//Main

```
public static void addContact(){ //MobilePhone.addContact necesita un argumento de tipo Contact asi que como argumento uso
    celular.addContact(new Contact()); //new Contact que invoca al constructor de la clase Contact
}

public static void searchContact(){ //NO FUNCIONA
    System.out.println("Enter name to search for:");
    String name = scanner.nextLine();
    scanner.nextLine(); //clean buffer
    boolean exists = celular.findContact(name);

    if(exists){
        System.out.println("Contact found");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Contact doesnt exist");
    }

}
```

//Movil class

```
public void addContact(Contact contact){
    contacts.add(contact); //agrega al arrayList el objeto Contact pasado
    System.out.println("Contact " + contact.getName() + " added. Number " + contact.getNumber());
    //del objeto Contact pasado, usa los getters de la clase Contact para imprimir nombre y numero
}

public boolean findContact(String name){

boolean exists = contacts.contains(name);
if(exists){
    return true;
} else{
    return false;
}

}
```

//Contacto class

```
public class Contact {
private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
private String name;
private int number;

public Contact() {
    System.out.println("Enter name");
    this.name = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter number");
    this.number = scanner.nextInt();
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public int getNumber() {
    return number;
}
```

Comment: Contains busca un Objeto en concreto, y para que la JVM pueda buscar un objeto en una lista, el objeto debe implementar los métodos Equals y HashCode, en el método Equals  define que hace que un objeto sea igual a otro, en este caso el nombre. De lo contrario se desea buscar todos los contactos que contengan el nombre buscar, lo puede hacer con un Stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos por partes, para empezar no es una buena idea que la clase `Contact` tenga un `Scanner` de teclado, ya que por cada contacto que creas va a tener un `Scanner` asociado, lo que podrías hacer es crear un método en otra clase que pida el nombre y el teléfono de un contacto y que a partir de ahí, genere un nuevo objeto `Contact`.

Ese es parte del problema, ya que la lista `contacts` es una lista de objetos `Contact`, es decir, que tiene la siguiente estructura, imaginando que tiene un contacto con nombre: nombre1 y telefono:666666666:

```
contacts:[
    Contact:{
         Scanner sc,
         name:"nombre1",
         number: 666666666
    }
]
```

Por eso el `contains` con un `name` te devuelve `false` siempre. Porque la lista no contiene `names`, contiene `Contacts` que dentro tienen `name`, y `contains` llama internamente a `equals`de los objetos que quieres comparar.

Yo te propongo una solución:

Sobreescribir el método `equals` en el objeto `Contact` para que devuelva `true` sólo con el nombre (de lo contrario comparará atributo por atributo y **SOLO** si todos son iguales devolverá `true`), para ello tienes que meter en tu objeto `Contact` el siguiente código (puedes modificarlo si quieres que compare de manera diferente, pero eso ya a tu elección):

```
 @Override
 public boolean equals(Contact contacto){
      if(this.name.equals(contacto.name)){
          return true;
      }
      else{
          return false;
      }
 }
```

Y en el método `findContact`en lugar de pasarle al `contains` un `String name` debes pasarle un objeto `Contact` con el `name`que tu quieras:

```
Contact contactoABuscar= new Contact();
contactoABuscar.setName(name);
boolean exists = contacts.contains(contactoABuscar);
```